# Two problems: First is about starting my app and second is where to put my classes

Tags: android

this is my first app and it's a present for android people in Serbia...i'm not charging it. I finished it, but I have some problems. First problem is:
My first screen is alert dialog where I explained to user's what thay need to run my app. The problem is when i start my app again when(i guess) is destroyed from android system it dont show alert dialog. It shows an empty screen.I go out on home button come again and now it all okey. What's wrong??? Any idea?
Second problem is: My classes are all in one folder:src/test/projekat. When i start my app on phone it installs all 4 files which represent my 4 activitys in manifest. Is this the way it should happen??? Thanks a lot...
EDITED ALERT DIALOG CODE:

```
public class PronadjiKlopuActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Kreira AlertDialog sa dva dugmeta koji ce se pojaviti pri aktiviranju aplikacije
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        ad.setTitle("Vasa trenutna lokacija");
        ad.setMessage("Da bi ste koristili aplikaciju potrebno je da ukljucite internet konekciju i dozvolite koriscenje GPS satelita i wireless mreze za dobijanje lokacije.");
//        ad.setMessage("Da bi ste koristili aplikaciju potrebno je da dozvolite ocitavanje vase trenutne lokacije.");
        ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Dozvoli", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            //Klikom na dugme Dozvoli otvara se novi prozor
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface ad, int which) {
                Intent i = new Intent(PronadjiKlopuActivity.this, TrenutnaLokacija.class);              
                startActivity(i);               
            }
        });

        ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Ne dozvoli",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            //Klikom na dugme Ne dozvoli aplikacija se zatvara
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();

            }
        });

        //Mesto na kojem ce se pojaviti dialog
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wMLP = ad.getWindow().getAttributes();
        wMLP.x = 100;
        wMLP.y = 200;
        ad.getWindow().setAttributes(wMLP);
        ad.show();



    }

    //U slucaju pritiska dugmeta Back gasi se aplikacija
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
//      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
//      i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);    
//      startActivity(i);
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Comment: Your code, sir. Please show it to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
When i start my app on phone it installs all 4 files which represent my 4 activitys in manifest. Is this the way it should happen???
```

you have added this property in each of your activity tag in your manifest file:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

you should add this property to your activity in manifest which will be first one when your app starts..

for your alertDialog show your code..

Comment: Yes, I have it in every activity. I will remove it, but I have one question for you. If I want to show this AlertDialog just for the first time when my app is instaled and for the every other start of my app i want it to start from a second activity how can i do that??? Do you know?

Comment: then you should maintain a bool value in SharedPreference and use it to show for the first time....

Comment: I dont understend...when i remember bool value??? Do you mean that when i for the first time open my app i change bool value and when i open at for the second time i use intent to open second screen???

Comment: Check for bool value and if it is false set this boolean true and save it in SharedPreference and show the alertDialog(It will be case for first time) and if it is true then you should show the next screen which you want......

Comment: Okay...Thanks for an answer...you helped me so much... ;)))
Do you know anything about my first problem???

Comment: I will try that when i come home. I will let you know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following code only once to your starting activity in AndroidManifest.xml
It means that `SplashActivity` would be the first one to be called. In your case it would probably be `PronadjiKlopuActivity`

```
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:label="@string/app_nomine"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: if this is regarding the fact, that the dialog does not show up, that I would suggest you to put your dialog show method in onStart(), to be sure it's called every time activity appears on the screen.